# App crash when I run on iOS 12.5.5 version - dyld: Symbol not found: ___chkstk_darwin

Tags: swift, crash, ios12, xcode13.2

after updating Xcode 13.2.1 (13C100) when I run my app on iPhone 6(12.5.5) it's showing an error and the app is crashing.

```
    dyld: Symbol not found: ___chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/39152A4A-A4A7-4940-999B-A61D1D72C83C/Sq.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib (which was built for iOS 13.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/39152A4A-A4A7-4940-999B-A61D1D72C83C/Square Insurance.app/Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib
(lldb)
```

Comment: This is not a solution but note that the error explains that "libswift_Concurrency.dylib (which was built for iOS 13.0)", but you're running the app on iOS 12.5.5, so it's not super surprising that some function definitions may be missing. What is your deployment target version?

Comment: Keep using XCode 13.1 for running on iOS 12.X safely

Comment: deployment target version is 12.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue has been fixed with XCODE update : Version 13.3 (13E113)